# Sortable Accordian - how to minimize its width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I made a sortable accordion with jQuery UI, and it seems to be filling up the full width of the page.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#sortable

How can I set it so that it's width will be minimized, so it will be as long as the biggest group it has.

thanks

Comment: did you try setting the width of the <div> it is contained within?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a CSS style for the accordion id or ui-accordion class in that page as follows.

Adding width to the id

```
#accordion{
   width:300px;
}
```

or add to the css class

```
.ui-accordion{
    width:300px;
}
```

In this I have considered the width as 300px

Comment: this does control the width of it, but I don't want to hard code a size, I want to use auto, but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The page you ref'd has a link to a stand-alone example of the accordian, http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/sortable.html, which also expands to the full width.  So the first page constrains the accordian externally (outside of the accordian itself).  To control the width and other dimensions directly, use CSS to style the elements

Comment: Based on your original question, you'll want to set the width attribute.  If the app needs to make the element wider or narrower depending on the content, use javascript or jQuery to set the width dynamically.

Comment: but how do I get the width of the largest group?